# remove relative paths from bash script

Tags: bash

I have this bash script which I would like to call a file in the same directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit # Exit on error

# Enable script to run from anywhere
cd "$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"

source ./script/main
cd ../..

source ./scripts/test
cd ./packages/applicant/

yarn build
```

Is there anyway I can get rid of the relative paths or do this better.

I need to be in the right directory to call the npm scripts via yarn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the absolute path of the script directory with:

```
ABSOLUTE_PATH_OF_SCRIPT="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

This way you can avoid `cd` to another directory for the script till before calling `yarn build`. Once you have the absolute path, you can convert the `source` calls to absolute and remove the `cd` lines, e.g.

```
source "$ABSOLUTE_PATH_OF_SCRIPT"/script/main
source "$ABSOLUTE_PATH_OF_SCRIPT"/../../script/test
cd "$ABSOLUTE_PATH_OF_SCRIPT"/../../packages/applicant
yarn build
```

Although personally, the relative paths approach feels more readable. It is not clear what is the purpose of the `source` statements, and depending on the internals, they may require that you actually `cd` to those directories like in your initial script, but you can keep track of the script's directory in a variable like in this example to improve the readabilty.